# Generate YAML manifest from Kubernetes types

Tags: go, kubernetes

I'm looking into writing a tool that generates Kubernetes definitions programatically for our project.

I've found that the API types in Kubernetes can be found in `k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api`. I would like to output YAML based on these types.

Given an object like this:

```
ns := &api.Namespace{
    ObjectMeta: api.ObjectMeta{
        Name: "test",
    },
}
```

What's the best way to generate the YAML output expected by `kubectl create`?

Comment: try the yaml.v2 library and marshal with it, see if the output is compliant with kubernetes. https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml

Comment: That won't work, Kubernetes does not have yaml annotations. They seem to serialize to JSON and then convert to YAML, but I haven't found the right APIs yet to wrap it all in the correct envelope (including apiVersion and kind fields).

Comment: it's ugly but you might want to try to generate json and use python to properly format your json as yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, for future reference, here's what you might want to do:

```
package main

import (
    "os"

    "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/unversioned"
    "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/v1"
    "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/runtime/serializer/json"
)

func main() {
    ns := &v1.Namespace{
        TypeMeta: unversioned.TypeMeta{
            Kind:       "Namespace",
            APIVersion: "v1",
        },

        ObjectMeta: v1.ObjectMeta{
            Name: "test",
        },
    }

    e := json.NewYAMLSerializer(json.DefaultMetaFactory, nil, nil)

    err := e.EncodeToStream(ns, os.Stdout)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

This might not be the best practice (better suggestions welcome), but it does the job.

Comment: As a side note, this may be unnecessary if you're not planning on maintaining these manually. Kubernetes manifests can be defined in json or yaml. The file extension .yaml, .yml, and .json can be used. So you could just marshal to JSON and write it to a `.json` file if you're feeding the output to `kubectl`

https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 2):

Their API has updated, so this is how it looks like:

```
import k8sJson "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime/serializer/json"
...
serializer := k8sJson.NewSerializerWithOptions(
    k8sJson.DefaultMetaFactory, nil, nil,
    k8sJson.SerializerOptions{
        Yaml:   true,
        Pretty: true,
        Strict: true,
    },
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import (
    "os"

    v1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/runtime/serializer/json"
)

func main() {
    ns := &v1.Namespace{
        TypeMeta: metav1.TypeMeta{
            Kind:       "Namespace",
            APIVersion: "v1",
        },

        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            Name: "test",
        },
    }

    e := json.NewYAMLSerializer(json.DefaultMetaFactory, nil, nil)

    //err := e.EncodeToStream(ns, os.Stdout)
    err := e.Encode(ns, os.Stdout)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```